# Create User Defined Portion of Spherical Shape in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a sphere in THREE.js (I'll call it the master sphere).  My user has the ability to click multiple points on the sphere to mark the corners of a polygon.  The points themselves are represented as spheres in 3D space, and rest on the surface of the master sphere.  Once there are three or more points are placed, the user can close them and build a polygon.

At this point I would like to create a polygon just above the surface of the master sphere.  This polygon should be in the shape of the one that the user just built, and also elevated just above the surface of the master sphere.

I thought that I would be able to create a polygon at the surface of the sphere and then displace each vertex on its normal using a vertex shader so I built a shape using THREE.Shape and THREE.ShapeGeometry.  This results in a 2D shape on the z axis so  I next translated the shape to the surface, and then used different combinations of the THREE.SubdivisionModifier and THREE.TessellateModifier in an attempt to build vertices for the shader to displace.  ALso, the shape wan't even visible after translation if I didn't use a modifier.

I'm currently using the following combination of the two, but this results in a very distorted shape.

```
// Create a new instance of the modifier and pass the number of divisions.
var subdivisionModifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(3);
var tessellateModifier = new THREE.TessellateModifier(8);

// Apply the modifier to our cloned geometry.
for(var x=0; x<6; x++) {
    tessellateModifier.modify(polyGeometry);
}

subdivisionModifier.modify(polyGeometry);
```

Results in the following:
[image: polygon example]
The yellow outline is the desired shape, while the blue outline is what is created.  The green wireframe is the master sphere.

I built a JSFiddle for my project here:
[Globe with elevated polygon](http://jsfiddle.net/reggie3/unowf47t/25/)

As you can see, the resulting polygon doesn't take the desired shape.  In the end I guess I need to know if I'm going down a dead end path, and if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Comment: There's a problem when (control-)clicking the fiddle: `TypeError: intersectionArray[0] is undefined`.
Do I understand correctly: are you trying to define a surface area on the globe delineated by a polygon?

Comment: You do understand correctly.  I was able to activate clicking on the globe by clicking in the white space on the window.  I don't get the error you're getting.  I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the create a mesh with many vertices by decreasing the maximum edge length parameter passed to THREE.TessellateModifier and increasing the number of applications.  I didn't need the subdivision modifier afterall.

Final code is below:

var tessellateModifier = new THREE.TessellateModifier(.01);

```
        //subdivisionModifier.modify(polyGeometry);

        // Apply the modifier to our cloned geometry.
        for(var x=0; x<25; x++) {
            tessellateModifier.modify(polyGeometry);
        }
```

Additionally, there's not need to resort to a vertex shader to distort the mesh.  Using the setLength() function of each vertex lets you displace them to create a curved polygon that is just above the surface of the globe.

```
//push each vertex to just above the surface of the globe
            for(var i = 0; i < this.polyMesh.geometry.vertices.length; i++){
                this.polyMesh.geometry.vertices[i] = this.polyMesh.geometry.vertices[i].setLength(this.surfaceDisplacement);
            }
```